# How to Install mongod with libcurl4?

Tags: mongodb, debian

Debian10 upgraded to libcurl4 and as a result, the installation of mongo server fails. Is it possible to run mongod with libcurl4?

On executing the mongod binary I get /usr/bin/mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/bin/mongod).

On trying to install libcurl3 I get the message that libcurl4 replaces it.

Comment: So far, this is the most promising solution I found, but I am not really comfortable with adding a PPA for this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061431/how-to-have-both-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-installed-at-same-time

Comment: It may be possible to simply use the deb file built for ubuntu instead of the one built for Debian.

Comment: Nope. Same issue.

Comment: This solved my issue on Ubuntu 18.04 (Debian-based too). https://askubuntu.com/a/1110328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is outdated. There is now a Debian10 version available.

**(Old answer)**
For now, simply use the version built for Ubuntu 18.4
Visit https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community and download the Ubuntu 18.4 version.
Ubuntu is based on Debian Testing, so there shouldn't be issues regarding using that version. Mongo will probably update their Debian version soon. Then you may install the Debian10

**There is already a Debian 10 version available in the same link.**

After downloading you can use this command to install (provided your shell is in the same folder as the downloaded package):

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-server*.deb
```

Comment: Simply replace "server" to "shell" to download MongoDB Shell :)

Comment: Link is broken. Also, could you add some step by step instructions?

Comment: There is now a debian10 version available. It shouldn't be necessary to use Ubuntu 18.4 version anymore.
Added instructions on installing the downloaded debian package.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve libraries dependencies issues is to use a docker container.

For example in that case, once docker-ce installed, you could run something like this :

```
docker run -d --name mongo-4.0.9  -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017  --restart unless-stopped -v /var/lib/mongodb:/data/db mongo:4.0.9
```

In that way, you do not depend on your system dependencies.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same issue on Debian 10 (Buster) in 2021-07 after I was following the official MongoDB documentation for setting up an old Mongodb version (4.0) on a new Debian machine.

After following these steps you will have licurl3 along with libcurl4 installed at the same time. I haven't discovered any broken dependencies until now.

```sh
root@mongo21-1 ➜  sources.list.d  cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb_org_deb.list
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.0 main
EOF


root@mongo21-1 ➜  sources.list.d  apt update



root@mongo21-1 ➜  sources.list.d  apt install -y mongodb-org-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So the issue is that Mongo requires explicitly libcurl3, but it is no longer supported in the latest Debian 10 version. However you can do the following:

```sh
root@ecollect-mongo21-1 ➜  sources.list.d  cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oldstable.list
deb http://security.debian.org/ oldstable/updates main
EOF

root@mongo21-1 ➜  sources.list.d  apt update

root@mongo21-1 ➜  sources.list.d  apt install -y libcurl3/oldstable

root@mongo21-1 ➜  sources.list.d  apt install -y mongodb-org-server
```

Works like a charm!

EDIT: Here are some ansible tasks to automate this:

```yaml
---

  - name: Ensure deb keyring for mongodb
    apt_key:
      state: present
      url: https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc





  - name: Ensure mongodb deb source
    apt_repository:
      filename: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repo-mongodb_org-debian-apt
      state: present
      repo: "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.0 main"




  - name: Ensure libcurl3 source
    apt_repository:
      filename: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oldstable.list
      state: present
      repo: "deb http://security.debian.org/ oldstable/updates main"





  - name: Install packages - mongodb-org-server
    apt:
      name: mongodb-org-server
      state: present


  - name: Install packages - mongodb-org-shell
    apt:
      name: mongodb-org-shell
      state: present


  - name: Install packages - mongodb-org-tools
    apt:
      name: mongodb-org-tools
      state: present
```